# Find test step by partial name using groovy in soapui

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to disable test steps with a particular string in it in the entire soap ui project.

How to find teststeps containing text 'WSDLCall' in my soapui project and disable them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the **groovy script** which does what you needed.

So, add a groovy script test step in the same project where you want to disable the test steps. And you can find the comments for the script appropriately.

```groovy
/**
* this groovy script disables all the test steps
* whose name contains the string specified in the
* variable 'stepNamePatternToDisable'
**/

//You may change the pattern required
def stepNamePatternToDisable = 'WSDLCall'

//Get the project object
def project = context.testCase.testSuite.project

//Loop thru the suite lise
project.testSuiteList.each { suite ->  
    //Loop thru the case list
    suite.testCaseList.each { caze ->
        //Loop thru the step list of the specific case
        caze.testStepList.each { step ->
            //if step name contains the given pattern, then disable, enable otherwise.
            if (step.name.contains(stepNamePatternToDisable)) {
                step.disabled = true
            } else {
                step.disabled = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```